# What's the difference between `extern int (x)[]` and `extern int x[]` in C?

Tags: c, global-variables, extern, variable-declaration

There is declaration `extern int (x)[]` at the end of [this](http://untroubled.org/articles/cdecls.txt) article. Are the parentheses doing anything or they are just for confusion?

My guess would be that with parentheses `x` is an array of external integers (and that's what the article says), but without those `x` would be an external array of integers. If this is true, how would the definitions differ? Wouldn't they both be `int x[]`?

Comment: "they are just for confusion"

Comment: Isn't an external array of `int`s the same as an array of external `int`s?

Comment: If you're looking into how to read C declarations, I feel obliged to mention the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, the parens are not doing anything there. The article you link to explains why:

> The simplest way to differentiate the two is to look at the placement
>   of the type specifiers.  If a type specifier immediately follows a
>   left parenthesis, that parenthesis is the start of a function
>   descriptor and the type is part of a function parameter. Empty
>   parentheses also signify a function.  Otherwise the parentheses are
>   grouping (perhaps unnecessarily, but it's better to have too many than
>   too few) the expression.

Also note that "array of external ints" and "external array of ints" are the exact same thing -- the "extern-ness" always goes to the object being declared, which in this case is an array. Personally I think the first way to describe it is technically inaccurate and simply confusing.

Comment: I was just about to quote this EXACT block from the page. It's a very nice way to tell what the parentheses actually mean. :)

Comment: Thanks, I read that block myself but couldn't figure out if this was the unnecessary case :)

Comment: @Juris: I edited the answer to clarify a bit what exactly is external.

Answer (score 1):

The paranthesis are of no significance in that case. Normally, you use paranthesis for either function-pointers or to mark stronger binding, as all Operators have a different Level of binding.
The `extern` keyword marks, that this is just a declaration, but the actual definition of this array will happen somwhere else.